# ID Element return when giving as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website for school and we where working with function. Now i got a litle "problem"

i am using jquery to change the DOM and made a function where you can choose which location you are adding the element to.

Something like this:

```
function functioname(parameter){

console.log(parameter);
}
```

when i call this function like this:

```
functioname("#id");
```

i will return "#id";

But if i call it like this:

```
functioname (id);
```

I get return with the whole div and his children. How can this happen? 
And why works this only with divs.

It isn't really a problem i was just wondering how this works.

Thanks in advance if somebody could explain what is happening here.

Comment: What is the `id` variable?

Comment: In some browsers when you have an element with an id and you just use the id of that element it looks through the document and finds the element. You should not use that since it is an old deprecated practice.

Comment: You are just passing a string value into your function when you use `functioname("#id");` Passing `id` to the function might be a variable holding some other datatype.

Comment: @epascarello window.id isn't deprated, in fact it has been standardised in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object I'm not saying it is a 'cool' feature though EDIT: the document one is deprecated indeed

Comment: the context that you are using `return` is innappropriate and misleading. `return` is a key word in javascript that tells a function its job is finished and allows it to give a value back to its caller. in your code you dont use the `return` keyword, you just print (console.log) the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first function you are passing the string and in the second example you are passing the window object. Same as we pass an object with "this"

```
<div onclick= " functionname(this); "> </div>
```

here we get the complete object inside the function.

Comment: I think that is exactly what is happening. But do you maybe now if this is a reliable way to work?

Answer (score 2):

The `window.id` will find a DOM element whose `id` it matches. For example, `window.mydiv` will find:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

However, this not a recommended practice.

> As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the Web platform, for example. Instead of this, use document.getElementById() or document.querySelector().

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Answer (score 0):

In first line of code "#id" you are passing the string. it's return the string also as you says.

in second you pass object id that you have earlier in your code. This is maybe why you got the different result.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the `window` object. The window is pretty cool in that it allows you to declare global variables from anywhere on the fly. Take the following code for example

```
//the following three lines of code do the same thing
//create a global variable and store a value in it
window.a = 1;
window["b"] = 2;
var c = 3; //this one is most used though

function g() {
    //the following three lines of code do not do the same thing
    window.d = 4; //global
    window["e"] = 5; //global
    var f = 6; //local
}

g();

console.log(a); //prints 1
console.log(b); //prints 2
console.log(c); //prints 3
console.log(d); //prints 4
console.log(e); //prints 5
try {
    console.log(f); //ERROR
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

console.log(window.a); //prints 1
console.log(window.b); //prints 2
console.log(window.c); //prints undefined
console.log(window.d); //prints 4
console.log(window.e); //prints 5
console.log(window.f); //prints undefined

console.log(window["a"]); //prints 1
console.log(window["b"]); //prints 2
console.log(window["c"]); //prints undefined
console.log(window["d"]); //prints 4
console.log(window["e"]); //prints 5
console.log(window["f"]); //prints undefined
```

It is important to know that `obj.prop === obj["prop"]` is always true in JavaScript. That is why the last two sets of tests have the same results. Also important is `prop === window.prop` unless you declared prop using `var prop;`. This is because JavaScript secretly uses the special keyword `using` on the `window` variable at all times unless otherwise specified.

All browsers make DOM elements available via id using `document.getElementByID` but some browsers are nice enough to set up some variables for you so you don't have to write all that code. Imagine that a browser runs this script before any of your scripts do

```
(function(context) {
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i];
        if (tag.id) {
            context[tag.id] = tag;
        }
    }
}(window));
```

Which fills the window variable / global scope with tags that have ids.

Here are a bunch of examples. http://jsfiddle.net/Lk345zez/